# Avoid list opening when clicking a custom Token with react-bootstrap-typeahead

Tags: reactjs, token, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using the multiple token configuration and I want to create a custom token, so I just extend tokenContainer as the documentation says:

```
const TokenSkill = tokenContainer(props => {
    return <div
      onClick={(event) => {
          event.stopPropagation();
          props.onClickCustom(event);
      }}
      className="tokenSkill">{props.children}
      <span onClick={() => props.onRemove()}
    ><i className="fa fa-times crossButton" /></span>
    </div>
});
```

I want some data to display when a token is clicked. I've implemented my onClick version. But whenever I click it, the filter panel shows. It seems it is grabbing the same event when clicking in the filter box.

I've created this codeSandbox as example https://codesandbox.io/s/o9r23yklq9
If you search a token (try with "house") and add it on the list, when you click in the token it will display the filter list along with an alert. It should only show that list when clicking in an empty space on the filter list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. You're not passing all the `tokenContainer` props to your custom token. Among those props is an `onFocus` handler that stops propagation of the click to the parent, ie: the input.
2. Because you're using a `div` as the containing element, you need to set a `tabIndex` for the token to retain focus.

The following should work:

```
const TokenSkill = tokenContainer(props => {
  return (
    <div
      {...props}
      onClick={(event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
        props.onClickCustom(event);
      }}
      className="tokenSkill"
      tabIndex={0}>
      {props.children}
      <span onClick={() => props.onRemove()}>
        <i className="fa fa-times crossButton" />
      </span>
    </div>
  );
});
```

Here's a working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/74n5rvr75x